# How to capture logs from native python logging module in gunicorn?

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn, python-logging

I have a python flask/gunicorn project which includes the standard flask logging code. However, some of my code may not run in an application context (it has its own unit tests, including some fairly complicated functions in other files). These files use the native python logging mechanism. How do I capture those logs and write them to the same log file as the gunicorn/flask logs?

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
     app.logger.info("index hit")
     return jsonify("ok")
```

And I know the trick to capture the logging output and make it write to the gunicorn log:

```
if __name__ != "__main__":
    gunicorn_logger = logging.getLogger("gunicorn.error")
    app.logger.handlers = gunicorn_logger.handlers
    app.logger.setLevel(gunicorn_logger.level)
    app.logger.info("Gunicorn logging enabled")
```

However, I have other code which **may not run within an application context**. For example, it's tested in a unit test.

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def my_external_function(*args):
   logger.info("My function has been called")
   # do something
```

When I invoke gunicorn in the usual way:

```
gunicorn app:app -b 0.0.0.0:8080 \
    --access-logfile /var/log/myapp/access.log \
    --error-logfile /var/log/myapp/error.log \
    --log-level INFO
```

Everything that starts with `app.logger.` will write to `error.log` while the code using the native python logging (`logger...` or `logging.`) will write to stdout.

Comment: Does it work with `gunicorn ... --capture-output`?

Comment: I think this option would overwrite the error log file or create race conditions

Answer (score 0):

Confirm that the app logger is in a different context by inspecting `logging.root.manager.loggerDict`. If so, separate processes writing to the same file sounds problematic.
It maybe be suitable to merge separate files in a viewer. Configure your logger to have a file handler and have the same formatting as the Flask logger. Get a tool like LogMx that has the option of merging two logs into the same pane, interleaving according to timestamp.